# Why does Position sticky not working in safari?

Tags: html, css, safari, position, sticky

I am scratching my head from last five days, but not able to find solution, Read tons of articles, did research but no luck

Refer the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/v3u8pdk2/

Here,

Only on right side I have three children.
Third child's width can be more than parent, so I have applied `overflow: auto` to `right-side` div for horizontal scrolling

I want `first-right-child` and `second-right-child` to be sticky, so when user scrolls only third child should scroll.

It is working as expected in chrome and FF. But somehow its not working in safari.

Any help would be appreciated

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.left-child {
  width: 25%;
  border-right: 1px solid;
}

.right-child {
  width: 75%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.first-right-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}

.second-right-child {
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
}

.overflowing-container {
  width: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="left-child">
    LEFT CHILD
  </div>
  <div class="right-child">
    <div class="first-right-child">
      FIRST RIGHT CHILD
    </div>
    <div class="second-right-child">
      SECOND RIGHT CHILD
    </div>
    <div class="third-right-child">
      THIRD RIGHT CHILD
      <div class="overflowing-container">
        Overflowing
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: block;` to the sticky element or simply wrap it in a div. Position sticky causes problems when its direct parent has overflow settings because it transforms the element to relative.
If these don't work then try adding `position: -webkit-sticky;`

Comment: Why do I have to add `display: block`? It's default for `div`

Comment: i editted my answer to include the response

Comment: Still no luck https://jsfiddle.net/apyq3kw0/

Comment: Are you on windows or mac? Because Apple no longer offers Safari updates for Windows.
Also copy my CSS here:
`.parent {
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.left-child {
 width: 25%;
 border-right: 1px solid;
}

.right-child {
 width: 75%;
 overflow: auto;
}

.first-right-child {
 position: sticky;
 left: 0;
}

.second-right-child {
 position: -webkit-sticky;
 position: sticky;
 left: 0;
}

.overflowing-container {
 width: 1500px;
}`

Comment: I am on mac.....

Comment: My safari version is 13, As per https://caniuse.com/?search=sticky we don't have to use `-webkit` for sticky position for safari 13

Comment: oh well i cant do much from here since i dont have a mac i cant test things. good luck tho

Comment: This is not working